# unit test the captcha in python flask

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

in flask application I have a form for register

```
class RegisterForm(BaseForm):
    phone_or_email = StringField('user', validators=[input_required()])
    password = PasswordField('password',
                             validators=[Length(min=6, max=20),
                                         input_required()])
    captcha = StringField('captcha',
                          validators=[Length(min=4,max=4)])
    submit = SubmitField('submit')

    def validate_captcha(self, field):
        if field.data != str(session['CAPTCHA_NUM']):
            raise ValidationError('captcha error')
```

In the test code

```
def test_phone_register(self):
    response = self.client.post(url_for('auth.register'),
                                data={
                                    'phone_or_email' : 'no-reply@g.cc',
                                    'password': 'google',
                                    'captcha': 1234
                                })
    self.assertTrue('captcha error' in response.get_data(as_text=True))
```

the problem is that in the unit test I  don't know how to get the captcha.because the catpcha is in the session , should I just ingore it when test user registeration?

Comment: Do you *have* to have the real captcha? Are you just trying to test the behaviour with a type of response you get from the captcha behaviour? Maybe this might be a good place to use mocking?

Comment: I need to have the captcha, just need a way to test it ...

Comment: I solve the problem by fake a session in context manage.